# Where is the best place to find ores for armour sets?

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I have progressed a lot through the game, I have great tools and weapons and a big house. And now I've decided to put all the armour sets on mannequins in my house. I managed to craft a lot of them, but I didn't have enough of some materials. (Such as Platinum, Adamantite, Chlorophyte, etc...)

I was wondering what the best way to find such materials would be? I already have the Shroomite Digging Claws so I can dig fast.

Comment: Note that if you need the alternate hardmode ores (there are 6 in total, you only generate 3 in any world) you can create another world and carry your resources over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are actually quite a few "alternate" ores and I'll list them.  Note that I skip tiers that don't have alternate ores.  You'll need to generate several worlds to roll each of these ores, but here's the ones you need to hit.  Note that there are armors from other ores and materials if you want to be completionist.

**Normal:**

- Tier 1: Copper/Tin
- Tier 2: Iron/Lead
- Tier 3: Silver/Tungsten
- Tier 4: Gold/Platinum
- Tier 6: Demonite/Crimtane

**Hardmode:**

- Tier 9: Cobalt/Palladium
- Tier 10: Mythril/Orichalcum
- Tier 11: Adamantite/Titanium

Note that Chlorophyte will not spawn until you defeat each mechanical boss.

As for finding them, general mining tips:

1. By far the biggest ore finding aid is the **Spelunker Potion**. To make it you need *Blinkroot*, *Moonglow*, *Gold* or *Platinum* *ore* and a *water bottle*.  This lights up all ore on the screen (playing at your highest possible resolution is a big help with this).  It lasts 5 minutes.  Making a stack of these will be the biggest single time saver/discovery multiplier you can get.  It's not alwys easy to tell the different tints the ores highlight as apart but this potion will radically alter your mining efforts.
2. Small/Medium worlds require less effort to dig around looking for stuff in.  Natural cave networks are a great place to start.
3. Carry torches, your brightest light "pet", and a *Starfury*.  The Starfury can be used to "probe" dark areas and get an idea of what lies around you.  Stars will fall through solid material but then "hit" when they enter into an open area and find a floor.  Saves tunneling time and can reveal ore deposits.
4. Your fastest digging tool is a must.  *Shroomite Claws* are excellent and their shorter range won't matter for basic tunneling purposes.  Boost attack speed to taste and go to town!  There's only two better digging options in the game, but they're strictly end game stuff.

There is one more thing you can do: use a map viewer program like More Terra.  I won't recommend you take this step though if you get frustrated trying to verify which ores you roll in a new world programs like this can at least reveal that information for you.  Armed with spelunker potions and fast digging, you honestly won't need a map viewer for anything else.

Comment: Spelunker potion is the best option, in my experience. I'd forgotten about the Starfury hack. Good info all around.

Comment: I'm playing on console, so some of these things won't work. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @GeorgeWillcox bleh, overlooked that. Removed references to desktop only stuff, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to find these ores is to find a natural cavern and to travel through it with placing torches.

An alternative way is to put dynamites in a vertical line and you can go underground with a rope really fast.

It should be easier to find Platinum because it's generated early-game. However, Adamantite and Chlorophyte ores are harder to find because you must be in [hardmode](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Hardmode). Also, you'll need better tools to mine them.